# Conditional Arrayformula Based on Dropdown Cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to get data from `A2:A27` to `E2:E27` when `E1=A1`, `B2:B15` to `E2:E15` when `E1=B1` and same as `E1=C1`, `E1=D1` what is the formula? (import Data Column to Column)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1geeweabJfkcCJDCbFuncxnCdHO5v1olos4QuoYT0YJM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(2,         MATCH(E1, 1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(E1, 1:1, 0), 4)))
```

[image: 0]